# VS code resets launch.json configuration after restart

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm writing c++ application in VS code. I've already configured launch.json and I saved it. After reopening VS code, launch.json resets to some "default" configuration. Why and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Did you open a new folder or the same folder? `launch.json` is separate for each folder

Comment: @AlanBirtles same project in same folder

Comment: Is it possible that the root of problem is in some preferences of VS code?